# Mapserver display empty map when i add more then 1 raster file in 1 table postgis

Tags: postgis, mapserver

Here is a part of mapfile with layer and WMS:

> WEB
>       METADATA
>           wms_title "Diplom"
>           wms_abstract "no matter"
>           wms_onlinesource "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=D:/Diplom/sample.map&"
>           wms_enable_request "*"
>           wms_srs "EPS    G:4326"
>       END
>   LAYER
>   NAME rastertable
>   STATUS       ON
>   TYPE         RASTER
>   DATA "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=Diplom user=postgres password=**** schema=public table=rastertable"
>   PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
>   PROCESSING "NODATA=9999"
>   END

I load 2 tif files to postgis db use raster2pgsql -a -t 1000x1000 1.tif 2.tif schema.table and psql query.

Mapserver 3.0.4
Postgresql 9.4.0.
Logfile from mapserver:

> [Fri Mar 20 15:31:30 2015].251000 CGI Request 1 on process 3480
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:30 2015].257000 msDrawMap(): rendering using outputformat named png (AGG/PNG).
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:30 2015].257000 msDrawMap(): WMS/WFS set-up and query, 0.000s
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:30 2015].260000 msDrawRasterLayerLow(rastertable): entering.
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:31 2015].263000 msDrawMap(): Layer 3 (rastertable), 1.006s
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:31 2015].263000 msDrawMap(): Drawing Label Cache, 0.000s
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:31 2015].263000 msDrawMap() total time: 1.012s
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:31 2015].377000 msSaveImage(stdout) total time: 0.114s
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:31 2015].378000 mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): 1.127s
>   [Fri Mar 20 15:31:31 2015].378000 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 021ACF58.

When i trying to use http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=D:/Diplom/sample.map&layer=rastertable&mode=map in my browser he is display white screen, but if i use Db Manager in QGIS my raster files displayed normally.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please elaborate your question - more information is needed for this to be a good question. Are there any error logs around which could provide you with information? What versions of the software are you using etc?

Comment: Is your URL perhaps from some other experiment because you do not make layer=work3 with your mapfile?

Comment: Link from other experiment:) but with other link it still same problem

Comment: When you use `mode=map` you are not using the WMS functionality.